issue while running react-native project in mac for ios device
when i build react-native app in mac for ios it shows this issues. i tried npx react-native start to run this project at that time i get this error in my project
i tried few fix thati have recived from git buyt et am unable to fix
error: /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Debugging/DebuggingOverlayRegistry.js: Class private methods are not enabled. Please add `@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods` to your configuration.
  117 |   };
  118 |
> 119 |   #findLowestParentFromRegistryForInstance(
      |   ^
  120 |     instance: ReactNativeElement,
  121 |   ): ?DebuggingOverlayRegistrySubscriberProtocol {
  122 |     let iterator: ?ReadOnlyElement = instance;




module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
        root: ['.'],
        alias: {
          '@api': './app/api',
          '@assets': './app/assets',
          '@components': './app/components',
          '@constants': './app/constants',
          '@navigation': './app/navigation',
          '@screens': './app/screens',
          '@service': './app/service',
          '@store': './app/store',
          '@translation': './app/translation',
          '@utils': './app/utils',
        },
      },
    ],
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "envName": "APP_ENV",
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "blocklist": null,
      "allowlist": null,
      "blacklist": null, // DEPRECATED
      "whitelist": null, // DEPRECATED
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true,
      "verbose": false
    }],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};

